# Xsens IMU driver on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ros, imu, xsens

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OS: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Processor: Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU E6550 @ 2.33GHz × 2
ROS Groovy

For the driver stack: http://ros.org/wiki/xsens_driver

as mentioned here:
http://answers.ros.org/question/56635/xsens-error-comunicating-with-ubuntu-1204/
the IMU device can not mapped in a node because of the impossibility to  read the USB device.

For the other driver stack: http://www.ros.org/wiki/lse_xsens_mti
when I try to make the building I got this error however I already downloaded and built "gps_common":

mkdir -p bin
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
[rosbuild] Building package lse_xsens_mti
[rosbuild] Cached build flags older than manifests; calling rospack to get flags
Failed to invoke /opt/ros/groovy/bin/rospack cflags-only-I;--deps-only lse_xsens_mti
Package gps_common was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gps_common.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gps_common' found
[rospack] Error: python function 'rosdep2.rospack.call_pkg_config' could not call 'pkg-config --cflags-only-I gps_common' without errors

Does somebody has an idea how to make an IMU working on ROS in Ubuntu 12.04?
Thank you very much,

Claudio

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/72370/xsens-imu-driver-on-ubuntu-12.04/) by [ClaudioS](https://answers.ros.org/users/4644/claudios/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-08-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on 2014-05-12**:
Make sure gps_common is in your path. Install the correct version catkin/rosbuild and build it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This seems to highly depend on the Xsens that you have. According to the question you linked the newer versions need an updated driver/interface from xsens for linux. The older ones should work with the currently available drivers.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0